# Finding cause of memory leak in pool allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a custom memory pool that I'm trying to use with STL containers, and I'm using the std::allocator template as a wrapper around my implementation. I'm having trouble tracking down the cause of a memory leak reported by Valgrind.

I have the allocator template set up like this:

```
    template <class T> class pool_allocator
    {
    public:
        typedef T                 value_type;
        typedef value_type*       pointer;
        typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
        typedef value_type&       reference;
        typedef const value_type& const_reference;
        typedef std::size_t       size_type;
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t    difference_type;

        template <class U>
        pool_allocator(const pool_allocator<U>&) {}

        template <class U>
        struct rebind
        {
            typedef pool_allocator<U> other;
        };

        pool_allocator(size_type blocks,
                          size_type size_of_each_block=sizeof(T)) :
                          _pool(new MyPool<T>())
        {
            _pool->create_pool(blocks, size_of_each_block);
        }

        ... etc.

   private:
        MyPool<T>* _my_pool;

        ... etc.
```

It's working okay for the most part, but when I attempt to use the allocator with a std::vector I'm getting memory leaks when the vector goes out of scope.

When the destructor for MyPool looks like the following, where "_m_mem_start" is the pointer returned from a call to "new" for a block array of bytes sized appropriately to hold n objects of type T:

```
~MyPool()
{
  delete [] reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(_m_mem_start);
  _m_mem_start = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(nullptr);
}
```

And the destructor of pool_allocator looks like:

```
~pool_allocator()
{
    delete _my_pool;
}
```

Valgrind reports problems like the following:

```
InvalidRead|====|Invalid read of size 8|
||Call stack:|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/include/MyPool.h|19|0x400E34: MyPool<A>::~MyPool()|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/include/pool_allocator.h|40|0x400CB4: pool_allocator<A>::~pool_allocator()|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/main.cpp|19|0x400B55: main|
||Address 0x5ab5ca0 is 32 bytes inside a block of size 48 free'd|
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so||0x4C2F24B: operator delete(void*)|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/include/pool_allocator.h|40|0x400CBC: pool_allocator<A>::~pool_allocator()|
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h|79|0x400E73: std::_Vector_base<A, pool_allocator<A> >::_Vector_impl::~_Vector_impl()|
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h|161|0x400F35: std::_Vector_base<A, pool_allocator<A> >::~_Vector_base()|
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h|425|0x400D69: std::vector<A, pool_allocator<A> >::~vector()|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/main.cpp|20|0x400B49: main|
InvalidWrite|====|Invalid write of size 8|

etc.
```

Which looks to me like I'm trying to read member variable data from a MyPool class object which has already been free-ed. Valgrind also reports that the bytes in the buffer, say 12 bytes times 10 for a pool size of 10 POD objects each of size 12, has been lost.

But if I change the destructor of pool_allocator to call the destructor of MyPool instead, like this:

```
~pool_allocator()
{
    _my_pool->~MyPool();
}
```

Valgrind reports:

```
Leak_DefinitelyLost|====|48 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2|
||Call stack:|
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so||0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long)|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/include/pool_allocator.h|28|0x400C0E: pool_allocator<A>::pool_allocator(unsigned long, unsigned long)|
/home/matt/Documents/C++/Pool/main.cpp|19|0x400AD3: main|
||Valgrind found 1 errors!|
```

Which looks like the MyPool internal buffer has been free-ed appropriately, but instead the member data internal to MyPool (always of size 48 bytes) has been leaked instead.

How should I rewrite these destructors so everything is released in the proper sequence?

Comment: [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)). You haven't provided a copy constructor or assignment operator. The compiler-generated ones simply copy `_pool` pointer, so you end up with multiple instances thinking they own the same `MyPool`, and all trying to destroy it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks. My main function just creates an instance of `pool_allocator<A>` and then creates a single `std::vector<A, pool_allocator<A>>`of some size. So the copy constructor of pool_allocator is being invoked when the instance is handed to the constructor of the vector?

Comment: You don't show the declaration of `_pool`.

Comment: Of course. Vector needs to make a copy of the allocator, to store internally.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay. As this is C++11 could I explicitly delete the copy/copy assignment ctrs and use a move ctr instead, to hand off the instance to the vector? At least at this point I don't think I want to worry about there being multiple copies of a pool_allocator wrapper holding the same resource floating around.

Comment: Vector constructors take the allocator by const reference; no moving away from that. Besides, an allocator is required to be copyable.